# Segmentation fault trying to dereference a pointer from a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I have a vector of pointers to objects that I am iterating through using std::vector::iterator`.  Since the element returned is itself a pointer I dereference the iterator twice, once to return the pointer and once to resolve the pointer to the actual object.

I'm trying to invoke a member function (`getClass`) that returns an std::string and I have tried both `(**it).getClass()` and `(*it)->getClass()` but both give me a segmentation fault.  I keep feeling like I'm missing something obvious.

partial function code:

```
void dataSet::createFolds()
{
   // Shuffle the data vector
   std::random_shuffle( m_records.begin(), m_records.end());

   std::cout << "STARTING MAIN LOOP.  THERE ARE " << m_records.size() << " RECORDS\n";
   // iterate through the data vector and assign each to a fold
   std::vector<dataRecord *>::iterator it = m_records.begin();
   while (it != m_records.end())
   {
      std::string currentClass = (*it)->getClass();  // SEG FAULT HERE
      .
      .
      .
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

The vector is m_records ... [code](http://pastebin.com/pw8bQyc2)

dataRecord is defined like this ... [code](http://pastebin.com/5c86tYGG)

In response to questions about filling the vector:

The data is read from a text file and I really don't want to post the entire thing unless I have to (212 lines) but the pertinent code for populating the vector is below.  The constructor for the dataRecord object takes a vector of field objects.  I use a temporary pointer, use new to create the object then push_back the pointer.

```
while ...
{
   std::vector<field> fields;

   // build the fields vector
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numAttribs; ++i)
      fields.push_back(field(data.at(i), attribTypes[i]));

   // create the new dataRecord
   dataRecord * newRecord = new dataRecord(fields);

   // add the record to the set
   m_records.push_back(newRecord);

   ++recordNum;
   std::cout << "read record " << recordNum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the bug is related to how you're populating the vector. Post the relevant code and we can take a look.

Comment: Your definitions are fine, but I guess the problem lies somewhere else. Maybe at the time you are filling the vector? Are you 100% sure that you do not insert any `NULL`s into the vector?

Comment: Could one or more of your pointers be dangling, i.e., pointing to something that was destroyed?

Comment: I was assuming that the problem was with dereferenceing since stepping through with gdb crashed right then.  I'm gonna go step through the constructor and verify whats being placed in the vector and the state of all the objects involved.

Comment: Stepping through with gdb it appears to be filling m_records correctly.  There are definitely no null elements.

Comment: The problem is in the code you *haven't* shown us. Please create a minimal, complete sample program and post it in your question. In the process of creating the sample, you may discover the bug on your own. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: replacing all the file input with static values seems to fix the problem.  I guess it's process of elimination from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the vector elements are badly initialized. Perhaps you have to test the code that fill the vector independently before testing to extract them. Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either the pointers in your containers are null, or they are dangling pointers to free'd memory.

Double check the code that fills `m_records`.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
std::string dataRecord::getClass() {return m_data.at(m_data.size() - 1).getTextData();}
```

You must to verify m_data.size() because could be 0, so you will get an exception of out or range.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create the new dataRecord
   dataRecord * newRecord = new dataRecord(fields);
```

I'm guessing the bug is in `dataRecord`'s constructor. Are you sure it's doing it's job properly?

Comment: Fields is a vector of field objects not another dataRecord so it isn't a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily apply to the OP's question but for those arriving here from googling...

If you're receiving segfaults on dereferencing vector iterators and are working in multi-threaded applications, remember that vectors aren't necessary thread-safe!

The following example is unsafe without mutex locks.

**Thread 1**

```cpp
myVector.push_back(new Object());
```

**Thread 2**

```cpp
std::vector<Object*>::iterator = myVector.begin();
for (it; it != myVector.end(); it++) {
    Object* obj = *it;
}
```

Instead, something like this should be done:

```cpp
myMutex.lock();
myVector.push_back(new Object());
myMutex.unlock();
```

**Thread 2**

```cpp
myMutex.lock();
std::vector<Object*>::iterator = myVector.begin();
for (it; it != myVector.end(); it++) {
    Object* obj = *it;
}
myMutex.unlock();
```

Comment: Also wanted to add that I'm still learning C++/multi-threading, so how I'm using mutex locks in this example may not be ideal.